# Rails Belongs to with includes second-order associations not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 nested models in a Rails App:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :insurance_policy
end

class InsurancePolicy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, -> { includes :user }
end
```

I am trying to to avoid doing:

```
InsurancePolicy.last.product.user
```

Using the include addition to the belongs_to method, I get following error message:

```
[10] pry(main)> InsurancePolicy.last.user
  InsurancePolicy Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "insurance_policies".* FROM "insurance_policies" ORDER BY "insurance_policies"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<InsurancePolicy:0x00007fc50a2d5a10>
from /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activemodel-5.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:430:in `method_missing'
```

Why is the method missing? Do I need to add a column user_id in my insurance_policies table?

I am following the official documentation of AR.

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book, -> { includes :author }
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :line_items
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

Is this what I am missing? I don't really understand it:

```
If you use the select method on a belongs_to association, you should also set the :foreign_key option to guarantee the correct results.
```

Comment: I think you miss `belongs_to :user` in `Product` model

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write it in my stackoverflow, yes in my code

Answer (score 0):

Calling `InsurancePolicy.last.user` is incorrect because `InsurancePolicy` model does not have an association with `User` model.

Association `belongs_to :product, -> { includes :user }` is incorrect too, because model `Product` has no association with `User` model. To make `includes` work properly you need to add it to `Product`:

```
belongs_to :user
```

After that `InsurancePolicy.last.product.user` should work.

**Update:**

There is no `belongs_to through` association which you could use to have direct access to `User` model from `InsurancePolicy`. To make `InsurancePolicy.last.user` work simply define that association as a method of `InsurancePolicy`:

```
def user
  product.user
end
```

Comment: sorry sorry, i forgot the association in stack overflow, not in my code. I deleted irrelevant lines, and unfortunately the belongs_to line. Still not working

Comment: What exactly not working? `InsurancePolicy.last.product.user`? Or `InsurancePolicy.last.user`?

Comment: I tried to avoid exactly the solution of your answer. As you see in my question, I didn't want to use a method for that, since in the documentation they explain how to do it, but unfortunately it's not working

Comment: As you can see in my question, what is exactly not working is InsurancePolicy.last.user, and I also showed the error